# How to override NUnit test results on retry

Tags: c#, nunit

I was trying to rerun failed case as below but while marking test case as pass on 2nd run getting below exception at Assert.Pass() step. How to resolve this error?

Exception:

```
 NUnit.Framework.SuccessException
   at NUnit.Framework.Assert.Pass(String message, Object[] args)
   at NUnit.Framework.Assert.Pass(String message)
   at CodedUI.NUnit2.TestMethod() in NUnit2.cs:line 80
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments,   Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
```

Code:

```
public void TestMethod()
        {

            run++;

            if (run == 1)
            {
                Assert.Fail();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Rerun..");
            Assert.Pass();

        }
```

Retrying in clean up as below.

```
 [TearDown]
    public void cleanup()
    {


        if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status==TestStatus.Failed)
        {
            var type = Type.GetType(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.ClassName);
            if (type != null)
            {
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                var method = type.GetMethod(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName);
                try
                {

                    method.Invoke(instance, null);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [`Assert.Pass` explicitly throws an exception](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.5) that test runners should catch, treat as success, and display any provided message. What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

This can't work because NUnit treats every exception, including its own as an error in the TearDown phase. At the time of TearDown, the result of the test is already recorded.

Comment: The point of having a tear down phase is that it occurs *after* the tests have run, attempting to re-run a test during this phase is nonsensical.

Comment: Ok, is there any other way to mark Test case passed when it get passed on rerun?

Comment: It would require a change to NUnit. Currently the retry attribute does what you want but you have to specify a fixed number for mac retries. You appear to want some other way to define the number of retries.